# Current number of count in own div with Javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, count, appendchild, createelement

I am trying to add an increasing count number when a button is clicked, within the container `<div>`.

My code is not working, what am I missing?

```js
let taskCounter = 0;

let addTaskFunction = () => {
  const container = document.querySelector(".container");
  taskCounter++;
  let counterInDiv = document.createElement(`<div> ${taskCounter} </div>`);
  container.appendChild(counterInDiv);
};

document.getElementById('addTask').addEventListener("click", () => {
  addTaskFunction();
});
```

```html
<h1>Your tasklist for today</h1>
<div class="container">
  <div class="inputPart">
    <input id="taskInput" value="" placeholder="Fill in the following task here" />
    <button id="addTask">Add task</button>
    <button id="removeAllTasks">Delete tasks</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you provide your HTML code?

Comment: <body>

    <h1>Your tasklist for today</h1>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="inputpart">
        <input id="taskinput" value="" placeholder="Vul hier de volgende taak in" />
        <button id="addtask">add task</button>
        <button id="removealltasks">remove task</button>
     
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </body>

Comment: This is working, but I want to put the taskcounter in an own div, like the other two. const textInput = `<div>${taskInput.value}</div>`;
const trashbox = `<div><i class="fa fa-trash-o" style="font-size:48px;"></i></div>`;
const taskDiv = document.createElement("div");
taskDiv.classList.add("myDiv");
taskDiv.innerHTML = `<div>${taskCounter}.</div> ${textInput} ${trashbox}`;
container.appendChild(taskDiv);
};

Answer (score 4):

You need to use the tag name (div) for [document.createElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) then set the innerHTML instead of using the actual HTML code.

```js
let taskCounter = 0;

let addTaskFunction = () => {
  const container = document.querySelector(".container");
  taskCounter++;
  let counterInDiv = document.createElement("div"); // <--HERE
  counterInDiv.innerHTML = taskCounter;
  container.appendChild(counterInDiv);
};

document.getElementById('addTask').addEventListener("click", () => {
  addTaskFunction();
});
```

```html
<body>
  <h1>Your tasklist for today</h1>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="inputPart">
      <input id="taskInput" value="" placeholder="Fill in the following task here" />
      <button id="addTask">Add task</button>
      <button id="removeAllTasks">Delete tasks</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Found it! I was trying to add the counter in the div directly. So what I did was creating an variable an added the current count number, wrapped these in div. Like this: that did the job. taskCounter++;
 let myCurrentCount = taskCounter;
 counterInDiv = `<div>${myCurrentCount}</div>`; thank anyway., hero.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this is the code you want:

```js
let taskCounter = 1;

const taskList = document.getElementById("taskList");

const addTaskBtn = document.getElementById("addTask");
addTaskBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  let task = document.getElementById("taskInput").value;

  let counterInDiv = document.createElement("div");
  counterInDiv.textContent = `${taskCounter++}: ${task}`;

  taskList.appendChild(counterInDiv);
});

const deleteTasksBtn = document.getElementById("removeAllTasks");
deleteTasksBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  taskList.innerHTML = "";
  taskCounter = 1;
});
```

```html
<h1>Your tasklist for today</h1>
<div class="container">
  <div class="inputPart">
    <input id="taskInput" placeholder="Fill in the following task here" />
    <button id="addTask">Add task</button>
    <button id="removeAllTasks">Delete tasks</button>
  </div>
  <div id="taskList"></div>
</div>
```

I made a few changes:

- You do not need a function for the event listener, you can put the code inside an anonymous function that is passed to the event listener
- `taskCounter` should start at 1, not 0
- If you want the delete tasks button to work, then you should put the tasks inside a different container that can be easily cleared. I used one with the ID of "taskList"
- `document.querySelector()` only selects a single element, but you gave it a class of "container". If multiple `<div>`s have the class "container", then you will run into problems.
- `document.createElement` takes a tag name as the parameter, not HTML code. You should use `document.createElement("div")` then set the `.textContent` to whatever you want.